# Postgres table update taking 40 minutes, ultimately failing

Tags: postgresql, database-performance

I'm trying to update the value of a column in all rows in a table with about 1 million records.

First few times I ran the query it hung and after 20 minutes I cancelled the query. I ran it again with EXPLAIN ANALYZE, and after 40 minutes this was output:

```
=# explain analyze update documents set state = 'archived';
NOTICE:  word is too long to be indexed
DETAIL:  Words longer than 2047 characters are ignored.
ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 17080 waits for ShareLock on transaction 14275765; blocked by process 1530.
Process 1530 waits for ShareLock on transaction 14273749; blocked by process 17080.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
Time: 2324900.382 ms
```

Here's the EXPLAIN output:

```
=# explain update documents set workflow_state = 'archived';
                                 QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on documents  (cost=0.00..220673.50 rows=900750 width=1586)
   ->  Seq Scan on documents  (cost=0.00..220673.50 rows=900750 width=1586)
```

Any idea what's going on?

Details:

```
PG version 9.3.7

Indexes:
    "documents_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "document_search_ix" gin (contents_search)
    "document_user_id_recvd_ix" btree (user_id, bill_date DESC)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "documents_biller_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (biller_id) REFERENCES billers(id) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
    "documents_billercred_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (billercred_id) REFERENCES billercreds(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    "documents_folder_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (folder_id) REFERENCES folders(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "documents_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "documents_vendor_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (vendor_id) REFERENCES vendors(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
Referenced by:
    TABLE "document_billcom_actions" CONSTRAINT "document_billcom_actions_document_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (document_id) REFERENCES documents(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "document_box_actions" CONSTRAINT "document_box_actions_document_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (document_id) REFERENCES documents(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "document_email_forwarding_actions" CONSTRAINT "document_email_forwarding_actions_document_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (document_id) REFERENCES documents(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "document_qbo_actions" CONSTRAINT "document_qbo_actions_document_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (document_id) REFERENCES documents(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "document_xero_actions" CONSTRAINT "document_xero_actions_document_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (document_id) REFERENCES documents(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "document_xerofiles_actions" CONSTRAINT "document_xerofiles_actions_document_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (document_id) REFERENCES documents(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "documenttagmap" CONSTRAINT "documenttagmap_document_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (document_id) REFERENCES documents(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "synced_docs" CONSTRAINT "synced_docs_doc_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (doc_id) REFERENCES documents(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Triggers:
    document_search_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON documents FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('contents_search', 'pg_catalog.english', 'contents', 'filename', 'account_name', 'account_number')
    document_updated_at_t BEFORE UPDATE ON documents FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_updated_at_column()
    documents_count BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE ON documents FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE count_trig()
    folder_document_count_trig BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON documents FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_folder_count()
    tags_in_trash_document_count_trig BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE ON documents FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_tag_trash_count()
```

Comment: it clearly says **deadlock** . may be some circular update dependency.

Comment: 1. PostgreSQL version, table details, foreign-keys, any triggers etc. please and 2. Which one of 1530 and 17080 was this update and what was the other transaction doing? 3. The explain is normally useful, but not in this case - you are updating every single row so a sequential scan is pretty much all it can do.

Comment: @RichardHuxton updated with details, thanks. Re #2 17080 was doing the update, no idea what 1530 was doing.

Comment: I can't really claim this is an answer, but the explanation is probably best laid out here: http://rhaas.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/deadlocks.html - I suspect interaction between one of your triggers and the other transaction (whatever it was).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in to this. If deadlocks weren't an issue, how long roughly / what order of magnitude should I expect a query such as this on a table with 1 million rows to take? The machine it's running on is 12 cores, 16GB mem. Load avg nearing 1.

Comment: In the presence of so many triggers of unknown functionality it is impossible to say. The number of cores is also not relevant.

Comment: I would start by restricting the query to `update documents set state = 'archived' WHERE state IS DISTINCT FROM 'archived';` (restrictions in the trigger conditions also could be wanted.)